# Remove div if exits after div and put inside the main div

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="error">
<input type="text" name="email">
<div class="error-message">Please Enter Email</div>
</div>
<div class="i-icon-div">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

I want to check div who has class i-icon-div after div class error // my remove and wrap code not woring

jQuery Code

```
if($(".error" ).nextAll(".i-icon-div:first").length > 0){
      alert("div exits");
      // $(this).nextAll(".i-icon-div:first").remove(); not working
     }
```

after then i need output like that

```
<div class="error">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <div class="error-message">Please Enter Email</div>
    <div class="i-icon-div">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this it what you want http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/e43dk/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the [next adjuscent sibling selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/)

```
var $error = $('.error');
$('.error + .i-icon-div').appendTo($error)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qz36M/)

Comment: @vikastyagi if you have multiple error elements then you need to use http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qz36M/2/

Answer (score 2):

**Here is your answer**

**You are using**

```
$(this).nextAll(".i-icon-div:first").remove();
//$(this) is null in code
//if you use .each you can get each element in $(this)
```

**Use**

```
$(".error" ).nextAll(".i-icon-div:first").appendTo('.error')
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$('.error').each(function(index, element) {
if($(this).nextAll(".i-icon-div:first").length > 0){
    $(this).nextAll(".i-icon-div:first").appendTo($(this))
}
});
```

For shorter code You can save selected element in variable like

```
$ele = $(".error" ).nextAll(".i-icon-div:first")
if($ele.length > 0){
              $ele.appendTo('.error')
    }
```

Here is jsfiddle which works great http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/e43dk/3/

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: i have some issue it add for all div has class error, i want to check after next div http://jsfiddle.net/e43dk/1/

Comment: Sorry for link Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/e43dk/3/

See its working great :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `$(this)` without right context, `if` statement is not `jQuery` function where this is using for current `element`. You can put the required element in some `variable` and later use it in `if` condition.

```
reqDiv = $(".error" ).nextAll(".i-icon-div:first");
if(reqDiv.length > 0){
  alert("div exits");
  //  reqDiv.remove(); 
  or
  $('.error').append(reqDiv);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to loop through all your `.error` and insert the icon after `.error-message` if it fulfil your requirement like below:

```
$.each($(".error"), function () {
    var firstIcon = $(this).nextAll(".i-icon-div:first"),
        errorMessage = $(this).find('.error-message');

    if (firstIcon.length > 0) {
        firstIcon.insertAfter(errorMessage);
    }
})
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L6PaL/)**