# How to append div just after main div?

Tags: jquery, html

How to append div just after main div

jQuery Code

```
var $icons = $('.error + .i-icon-div');
if ($icons.length) {
    $icons.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.appendTo($this.prev())
    })
}
```

Html Code

```
<div class="error">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <div class="error-message">Please Enter Email</div>
</div>
<div class="error">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <div class="error-message">Please Enter Email</div>
</div>
<div class="i-icon-div">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Output

```
<div class="error">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <div class="error-message">Please Enter Email</div>
</div>
<div class="error">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <div class="error-message">Please Enter Email</div>
    <div class="i-icon-div">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Need output like that

```
<div class="error">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <div class="error-message">Please Enter Email</div>
</div>
<div class="error">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <div class="i-icon-div">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="error-message">Please Enter Email</div>
</div>
```

I have discuss some similar here [Remove div if exits after div and put inside the main div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621134/remove-div-if-exits-after-div-and-put-inside-the-main-div)

Comment: You just asked this right? an hour back?

Comment: yes now some little bit changes i have tried but could not do, that's why i asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) here, so you can change:

```
$this.appendTo($this.prev());
```

to:

```
$this.insertBefore($this.prev().find('.error-message'));
```

Comment: Now worked like that $icons.insertBefore($icons.prev().find('.error-message'));

Comment: i have changes this line $this.insertBefore($this.prev().find('.error-message')) to  $icons.insertBefore($icons.prev().find('.error-message')); , then worked for me, u also edit in ur answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `~` not `+`

`var $icons = $('.error ~ .i-icon-div');`